# Unable to install drush on centos 7

Tags: drush

## ============================================================================

Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[drupal-make-drush-install]

## ============================================================================

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed

---

Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2'
   ---- Begin output of composer global require drush/drush:dev-master ----
   STDOUT:
   STDERR: Changed current directory to /root/.composer
   ./composer.json has been created
   Loading composer repositories with package information
   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
 Problem 1
   - Installation request for drush/drush dev-master -> satisfiable by drus
```

/drush[dev-master].
       - drush/drush dev-master requires php >=5.5.0 -> your PHP version (5.4.1
) does not satisfy that requirement.

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
   ---- End output of composer global require drush/drush:dev-master ----
   Ran composer global require drush/drush:dev-master returned 2

The available php-cli package version for centos is 5.4.16 so which version of drush should I install?